# How to fix ( 'vector' : undeclared identifier ) in my header file?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, header-files

I'm trying to create a function that calculates the average of all the numbers in my array. But when I run the code the vector in my header says its undeclared. What should I change ?

I have tried putting #include  in my header file and using namespace std; but it still doesn't fix my problem. I have also tried passing my function as reference.

Source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "math.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main()
{


    vector<int> notes;
    notes.push_back(8);
    notes.push_back(4);
    notes.push_back(3);
    notes.push_back(2);

     cout << average(notes) << '\n';

}
```

math.cpp

```
#include "math.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;



int average(vector<int>  tableau)
{  
    int moyenne(0);
    for (int i(0); i < tableau.size(); i++)
    {
        moyenne += tableau[i];

    }

    return moyenne / tableau.size();
}
```

math.h

```
#ifndef MATH_H_INCLUDED
#define MATH_H_INCLUDED

int average(vector<int>  tableau);

#endif  MATH_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: You don't `#include <vector>` in `math.h`. Also prefer to explicitely state scope with `std::` rather than `using namespace std;`

Comment: [`math.h`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math) is a C standard header. You should avoid using that file name for your header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add `#include <vector>`.
2. Use `std::vector` instead of just `vector`.
3. While at it, change the argument type to `const&`.

```
#ifndef MATH_H_INCLUDED
#define MATH_H_INCLUDED

#include <vector>

int average(std::vector<int> const& tableau);

#endif  MATH_H_INCLUDED
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `#include <vector>` in `math.h` instead of in `math.cpp`

Comment: I have already tried that and it still gives me the same errors

Comment: That is because in `math.h`, you did not specify the namespace, so either write `std::vector` or add `using namespace std;` in the header itself

Comment: Thanks I tried both #include <vector> and using namespace std; on their own instead of putting both at the same time dumb mistake.